# Как получить данные с другой формы или со state ReactJS

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

Имеется два композитных элемента, назовем их форма 1 и форма 2. Форма 2 состоит из инпутов и выпадающих списков. Пользователь заполняет данными эти компоненты и нажимает на кнопку (в форме 1) получения данных из формы 2. Вот теперь вопрос, как мне получить данные с другой формы? Пытался получить через ReactDOM.findDOMNode. Толку нет. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно сделать общее хранилище-состояние для обоих элементов. Почитайте про FLUX. Мне, например, очень нравится библиотека Baobab. Но если для вашего случая это стрельба по воробьям из пушки, то можно сделать что-то простенькое и самому.

Другой вариант: поместить обе формы в общий родительский компонент, и уже получать и передавать состояния через родителя.

Comment: Ну или еще проще: форма 1 может быть родителем формы 2 и получать из нее данные при помощи ref.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. Передавать через родителя, хранить стейт у него и через пропсы значения и метод изменения значения передать детям.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
   constructor(...args){
      super(args)
      this.state = {
         form1: {},
         form2: {}
      }
      this.updateForm = this.updateForm.bind(this)
   },
   updateForm(form, key, value){
       const state = Object.assign(this.state[form], {[key]: value})
       this.setState(state);
   }
   render(){
        return <div className = "forms">
                  <Form1 name = "form1" update = {this.updateForm} />
                  <Form2 name = "form2" update = {this.updateForm} />
               </div>
   }

}
```

Вариант 2. Взять одну из имплементаций flux. Я очень советую Redux.